# How set Bitbucket secret in symfony .env when deploy with capistrano

Tags: php, ruby, symfony, environment-variables, capistrano

i trying to set my bitbucket secret in my .env file during the deployment with capistrano but unsuccessfully.
I try to export my secret and use envsubst on my .env with command task in capistrano and it doesn't work.
Someone have an idea how i can replace or put my bitbucket secret in the .env during the capistrano deployment?

Example :
i want to replace $DATABASE_URL

DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL

Thank you in advance

I try to export my secret and use envsubst on my .env with command task in capistrano and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you validate that `$DATABASE_URL` is set? Try echoing the value to make sure it is set or use `set -u`   to ensure your script will fail if you are using an environment variable that isn't set

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by create script in capistrano to replace new variable in .env like this:

```
namespace :modify do
task :env do
    on roles(:app) do
        execute "sed -i 's/__DATABASE_URL__/$DATABASE_URL/g' #{release_path}/.env"
    end
end
```